# Moving a DIV using XUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, xui

I'm trying to create a dragging effect on a div using xuijs.
I don't really know which event to look listen too and what to do with it to make it slide.

I need it to follow the cursor of the mouse (Only move on the x-axis)

Heres an example of what im typically trying to do

```
<div id="parent" style="width: 100px; height: 20px;">
    <div id="slideMe" style="width: 50px; height: 20px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

If slideMe is clicked and dragged, it should move from one end to another (the html above is just an example, it is of course not entirely correct)

Anyone have a general idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Even Listener to mouse to capture mousemove.

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
```

Then you can move your div with `mouseMove` function. You can make that div fallow your cursor.

```
function mouseMove(e) {
    if (IE) {
      Xcord = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      Ycord = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    } else {
      Xcord = e.pageX;
      Ycord = e.pageY;
    }

    if (Xcord < 0) Xcord = 0;
    if (Ycord < 0) Ycord = 0;

    document.getElementById('slideMe').style.top = Ycord + 'px';
    document.getElementById('slideMe').style.left = Xcord + 'px';

    return true
  }
```

But before that you need to set your divs style like below

```
#slideMe{
     position:absolute;
}
```

**Edit: These functions make div to fallow your cursor. But you wanted to move it in another div to levf and right; Then you need to change these codes like below.**

Style:

```
 #slideMe{
     position:relative;
 }
```

Function:

```
function mouseMove(e) {
    if (IE) {
      Xcord = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
      Ycord = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
    } else {
      Xcord = e.pageX;
      Ycord = e.pageY;
    }

    if (Xcord < 0) Xcord = 0;
    if (Ycord < 0) Ycord = 0;

    //document.getElementById('slideMe').style.top = Ycord + 'px';
    document.getElementById('slideMe').style.left = Xcord + 'px';

    return true
  }
```

Comment: I like the answer, I can see it work but I need to tweak it a lot to make it work the way I need it too. Currently when I mousemove, slideMe shoots off to the right of the screen, it's basically doing 'left: currentX + pageX'. Also I need it only to follow the mouse when I move it inside parent. I'm sorry if I'm not making much sense. I'm trying my best to be as clear as I can :-)

Comment: I figured it out, all I had to do was set the eventListener to parent. then do Xcord = x.pageX - parent.offsetLeft. Thanks for the help!